# Get taks and emails from Outlook into Android app

Tags: android, outlook

I want to get Outlook tasks and emails and show them in my Android app.
How can I achive this with any API or with any other method?

Comment: You should make your research before asking. Is there anything you tried?

Comment: i do to much search on google but i cannot find any solution for this .i am  new in android.if you have best link for this send me.

Comment: no one now how to do this

Comment: A simple search leads to these, and potentially more. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations 
http://www.aspose.com/android/email-component.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [MailWise Email for Exchange & Outlook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syntomo.email&hl=en)
It will show your Outlook emails and help you prioritize conversation threads.